# Is there a way to assign list of colors to chart so that these are automatically taken for new series added?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, addin-express

On inserting a chart in Powerpoint ,series colors are taken from [image]

This dropdown .But what I want is to define my own list of colors.
* Untill now I was coloring series while inserting charts .But the issue is after inserting chart if user adds series color of new series is taken from this menu shown in picture.
* I am using AddinExpress on powerpoint

Comment: Chart colors are taken from the color theme in order starting with Accent 1. In your screenshot, you are showing the default Office color theme, because you haven't created a new theme. Here's my article on how color themes interact with charts: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2018/02/great-color-themes/

Comment: blog seems to be relevant but i am looking for code.@JohnKorchok

Comment: We don't write code for you. You post your code here, and we help you to fix it.